# How to send a JSON response and redirect to some html page after success in Node.js using express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication

I am trying to send a JSON response, and redirect the page at the same time. It is not happening. Is there any way to redirect in Express.js while sending some JSON response to client? I want to use this JSON response to render the value to the redirected HTML page.

My Code -

```
//I tried using the below code. But it is not working
const app = express();

app.get('/user', authenticationMiddleware, (req,res) => {

    res.send({name : "StackOverFlow", reason : "Need help!"});

    res.redirect('/user/me');

})
```

Expected result :

I should get the {name : "StackOverFlow", reason : "Need help!"} as response (I will use fetch() to get the response) in the redirected client side HTML.

Comment: It's not possible to send a response body for a redirect, what is the reason you would want to do so?

Comment: If you want to redirect once you get the response, why not send the redirect route in the JSON object and redirect in client?

Comment: Hi there, I have suggested an edit to format your code. In future you can highlight your code and press `ctrl`+`k` to format it.

Answer (score 4):

What you'll want to do is setup your response object to look something like the below:

```js
res.send({name : "StackOverFlow", reason : "Need help!", redirect_path: "/user/me"});
```

And then in the function callback on your client (where you're making the fetch request), you'll want to pickup the value of `response.redirect_path` and pass it into a JS redirect method.

You could use something like:
`location.href = response.redirect_path`

**Example usage (on the client-side)**

```js
fetch("http://yousite.com/endPoint")
  .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.redirect_path) { //optional check to see if a redirect path exists
      location.href = redirect_path;
    }
  })
})
```

Bear in mind, I'm assuming that the argument passed in your fetch response callback function is called 'response', if it is 'res' or something else, you'll have to adjust the code above accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should send json response to client side and under success function of your ajax call use window.open(redirecturl)

Let me know if it didn't help

Comment: Thanks for the help, mzparacha. :)